# Disadvantage of prediction interval vs confidence interval

Tags: confidence-interval, generalized-linear-model, prediction-interval

I have a linear regression model μ = 4.7937 - 0.0627t with Y ~ N(μ, σ^2), where t is temperature and μ is the expected number of accidents that happen.

At t = 50, μ = 1.66 and the confidence interval is (0.79, 2.53) and the prediction interval is (0.02, 3.30). My question is what is a disadvantage of the prediction interval at t = 50 from the following choices?

1) The prediction interval is very wide

2) The prediction interval results in an impossible value.

3) The prediction interval for Y is wider than the confidence interval for μ.

4) The prediction for Y depends on μ.

5) There is no deficiency in the prediction of Y.

I know 2) is wrong because it doesn't result in impossible values. I know 1) and 3) are true but are they really disadvantages? i.e. prediction intervals are naturally always wider than confidence intervals.

Could anyone provide hints to solve this problem?

Comment: It makes no sense to compare prediction intervals to confidence intervals.They serve different purposes.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Does this mean that the prediction interval has no deficiency/disadvantage in this case?

Comment: Confidence intervals express uncertainty in an estimate while prediction intervals represent uncertainty in a new observation.  Prediction intervals, say in regression, have additional uncertainty so are naturally wider than a corresponding confidence interval. If you are confused about the difference in various statistical intervals such as confidence intervals, prediction intervals,tolerance intervals, and Bayesian aposteriori intervals look at the excellent book by Hahn and Meeker titled "Statistical Intervals".